# Why is this syntax reported invalid CSS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm using the sassc-rails gem to compile my sass files. After upgrading from 2.x to 3.x I'm getting the following errors:

> ```
>    Failure/Error: #{$odometer-themes-selector}
>
>    ActionView::Template::Error:
>      Error: Invalid CSS after ",": expected selector, was ", .odometer.odomete"
>              on line 11:1 of lib/assets/stylesheets/odometer-themes.sass
>              from line 14:9 of app/assets/stylesheets/cars/show.sass
>      >> 
>         ^
> ```

The content of the lib/assets/stylesheets/odometer-themes.sass file looks like:

```
// Define the theme names beforehand in the $odometer-themes variable
$odometer-themes: () !default
$odometer-themes: append($odometer-themes, odometer-auto-theme)


// Default themes
$odometer-themes-selector: ()
@each $theme in $odometer-themes
  $odometer-themes-selector: $odometer-themes-selector, unquote('.odometer.#{$theme}')

#{$odometer-themes-selector}
  display: inline-block
  position: relative

  .odometer-digit
    display: inline-block
    position: relative

    .odometer-digit-spacer
      display: inline-block
      visibility: hidden

    .odometer-digit-inner
      text-align: left
      display: block
      position: absolute
      top: 0
      left: 0
      right: 0
      bottom: 0
      overflow: hidden

    .odometer-ribbon
      display: block

    .odometer-ribbon-inner
      display: block
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden

    .odometer-value
      display: block
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0)

      &.odometer-last-value
        position: absolute

  &.odometer-animating-up

    .odometer-ribbon-inner
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s
      -ms-transition: -ms-transform 2s
      -o-transition: -o-transform 2s
      transition: transform 2s

    &.odometer-animating .odometer-ribbon-inner
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%)
      -moz-transform: translateY(-100%)
      -ms-transform: translateY(-100%)
      -o-transform: translateY(-100%)
      transform: translateY(-100%)

  &.odometer-animating-down

    .odometer-ribbon-inner
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%)
      -moz-transform: translateY(-100%)
      -ms-transform: translateY(-100%)
      -o-transform: translateY(-100%)
      transform: translateY(-100%)

    &.odometer-animating .odometer-ribbon-inner
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s
      -ms-transition: -ms-transform 2s
      -o-transition: -o-transform 2s
      transition: transform 2s

      -webkit-transform: translateY(0)
      -moz-transform: translateY(0)
      -ms-transform: translateY(0)
      -o-transform: translateY(0)
      transform: translateY(0)
```

I fail to spot the problem